# Word that means to "press softly"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Example:

> I held the bee and [...] against my arm, to see whether it would
>   sting me.

I can't think of any suitable word. And the [Thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/press) only has synonyms that mean *pressing harder*.

Comment: The word that comes closest could be *dab*: "b. To press (something) lightly against an object or surface"  (TFD). Does it work?

Comment: I think "I held the bee _to_ my arm, ..." or "I held the bee _against_ my arm, ..." would convey the meaning.

Comment: The thesaurus link is on *people or person working in communication*. I.e "The press" meaning newspapers. No wonder you didn't find any suitable synonyms!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the word 'brush'? In the sentence you had given, the blanks would be filled in with [brushed it].

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

> I held the bee to my arm to see whether it would sting me.

or

> I pressed the bee gently against my bare arm to see whether it would sting me.

Answer (score 1):

I think each of the following signifies a gentle approach.

---

*"... and **set** it upon my arm"*

> **[Set](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/set)**: to place with care or deliberate purpose and with relative stability.

---

*"...and **touched** it to my arm"*

> [**Touch**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/touch): to bring a bodily part into contact with especially so as to perceive through the tactile sense :  handle or feel gently usually with the intent to understand or appreciate.

---

*"...and **neared** it to my arm"*

> [**Near**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/near): to come closer in space or time to someone or something.

---

*"... and **placed** it upon my arm"*

> **[Place](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/place)**: to direct to a desired spot.

Answer (score 0):

SNUGGLE

> A close and affectionate (and often prolonged) embrace

CARESS

> Touch or stroke lightly in a loving or endearing manner

Answer (score 0):

How about [**tap**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/tap)

"to hit somebody/something quickly and lightly"

Ex.:

> **He kept tapping his fingers on the table.**

Answer (score -1):

**'Apply'** means pressing just enough to put in contact, and your example will be:

> I held the bee and **applied it to** my arm, to see whether it would
> sting me.

Usually, they apply remedies, like ice to a bruise. With the bee, the verb looks as weird as the action itself.

Apply on [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/apply):

> ap·ply  (ə-plī′) v. ap·plied, ap·ply·ing, ap·plies v.tr.
>
> 1. To bring into contact with something; put on: *applied glue sparingly to the paper*.

**Usage examples:**

[vinylengine](http://www.vinylengine.com/turntable_forum/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=64204) forum:

> **Don't press, just apply gently** for just the time it takes to achieve a
> smooth round shape. Don't overdo it!

[Biopharm Leeches](http://www.biopharm-leeches.com/applying.html)

> **Applying** Leeches
>
> The animals should be **applied** in adequate numbers to the general area
> of maximal congestion. The head (or biting end) of the animal can be
> recognised by its searching movements, while the tail end is used
> mostly as a sucker for fixation. It is best to use the hungriest
> (normally the smallest) leeches first. Preferably do not use forceps
> forcibly on the leech.

Comment: Apply does not mean "press gently."  It means to put something on, like glue.  Your first example sentence, with the bee, makes no sense.

Comment: @Steven Littman  Really? What about this: Equipment Needed to Apply Leeches http://www.biopharm-leeches.com/applying.html ? Like a bee, leech is an insect, isn't it?

Comment: @javaNoobs- you really can't "apply bees" you can apply creams, lotions, salves, glue, pastes, and because leeches stick like glue you can apply leeches, but gently brushing a bee against your arm to see if it stings would not be a proper application of ***apply***.  Generally when you apply something you expect it to remain there.

Comment: @Jim Also you apply ice or wet towel to a bruise and keep holding it but it does not stick

Comment: Yes, but when you *apply* an ice pack you hold it there because it does not stick.

Comment: So, is there a clear distinction between 'applying' and 'pressing softly'? I do  not think so. In case of bee experiment, brushing is not efficient, the bee may be unable to reach the skin, so he would have to hold it applied to his arm.

Comment: Jim's observations are right, you don't apply a "living moving thing" to something. (I think the leeches is an exception) There is in any case an error in your first example: *I held the bee and applied to.."* It should be: *"and applied **it** to my arm"*. A better verb would be "placed it on",  or if you were daring or feeling brave: "*rubbed it against my skin*"

Comment: @Mari-LouA - thank you for your note, I added 'to'. As to applying living thing as an exception, maybe, but such an action is even more of an exception than applying leeches. In case of 'place' it is more often used as 'leave' on a surface rather than hold slightly against something.

Comment: Likewise *apply*, once you applied oil, cream, shampoo etc. the product "sticks" to the surface until it's washed off.